# Deleting files within a directory through remote 3rd party service

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to use a service called LogMeIn to delete folders within a user profile's directory. When run locally, this obviously works. Very simple, as I am fairly new to batch files.

```
pushd %homepath%\Tracing
Echo Y | DEL *.*
```

Now, where I run into the problem is when I run it through LogMeIn. This service is for deployment and sends it to all the machines linked to it. It has me put in credentials that will work on all of the machines (network admin) so it can deploy the batch file and there is no way to work around it. Instead of going to C:\Users\tirefire, it now goes to C:\Users\Admin. Any thoughts as how to efficiently navigate to the desired user profile that is currently logged in? Every system is identical. Windows 7 Service Pack 1.

Couldn't find anything online regarding this issue directly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `pushd "%userprofile%"` ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. It sends me to admin\tracing rather than the activeuser\tracing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logmein will only log onto the profile that you have setup to access that computer. For example if your credentials are admin/pass you will get the admin profile, for tirefire/pass you will log on as TireFire.

Prior to logging in you will not be able to see who is logged in.

This is not the answer your looking for but it is the limitation of the software.

You could use a batch like:

```
CD..
FOR /D %%P IN (*.*) DO DEL /S/Q %%P\TRACING\*.*
```

This will look in the folders under c:\users (/D) and assign all user folders to the variable (%%P) and delete (DO DEL) anything in the tracing folder (%%P\TRACING*.*) for all users on the machine.

Source: I use logmein daily to log onto machines that we service.